# nginx cache cookies issue

Tags: nginx, cache, fastcgi

I've configure nginx|php-fpm with nginx cache.

The problem i'm having is with the cookies and cache, i configure to bypass cookie name and some request_uri and working fine bypass it cool here.

Problem comes when passed few minutes if is signup or not my logged with different user and when change in different pages i'm logged with diffent user or same user.

When i see the header i see perfect fine is bypass by cookies if logged and when is not logged say hit, pages i setup as bypass says bypass but logged as an user (not logged)

Not sure what happen here i try everything and i can't find the reason for this issue.

nginx.conf

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/dor levels=1:2 keys_zone=dor:10m inactive=60m max_size=1024m use_temp_path=off;
```

vhost.conf

```
    set $skip_cache 0;
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* "confirm|feed|login|lost|logout|signup|admin|user|index.php|sitemap.php") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    if ($http_cookie ~* "mainsite") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    add_header Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {

        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_pass                    127.0.0.1:9002;
        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors        off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
        fastcgi_buffers                 256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
        fastcgi_cache                   dor;
        fastcgi_cache_valid             200 301 5m;
        fastcgi_cache_min_uses          3;
        fastcgi_cache_lock              on;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass            $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache_key               "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale         error timeout updating invalid_header http_403 http_500 http_503;
        fastcgi_cache_revalidate        on;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers          Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_no_cache                $skip_cache;
        include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is quite dangerous:

```
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
```

With the `Set-Cookie` in the values, you're effectively allowing to cache someone's login request. You need to either hide it from response via `fastcgi_hide_header` (which would break login feature, if not done correctly) or use `fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;` (which would break caching altogether, if you have a "bad" app, see below).

It is best to identify your "login location" (e.g. `POST /login`) and essentially create 2 cache configurations:

1. Login location. Neither `fastcgi_ignore_headers` nor `fastcgi_hide_header` are required. Do not include them.
2. Other pages location. This is required if your app unnecessarily starts session (sends `Set-Cookie`) for any page; quite many do.

   ```
   fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
   fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;
   ```

... and just as a bonus. NGINX is all great, but Varnish is quite flexible about manipulating both sets of client and upstream headers, e.g.:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.cookie !~ "mainsite") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }
}
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie && bereq.url != "/login") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for very detail explication i appreciate it.

Your two points, i not get it.

1. /login

Can you give me an example? i need to all fastcgi_cache and only not set fastcgi_ignore_headers

2. Other pages location, pages is required session is /user and /admin others just cache.

So, are you saying in whatever case not use fastcgi_ignore_headers 

I was thinking about using varnish but first i needed to know if I was going to have the same problem, i need to know exactly what is really problem i'm having, bad configuration, need especial configuration or my app have "bad app".

Comment: When I mean login location, I don't mean location that requires to be logged in. I mean very specific location where you submit login credentials. For example `/wp-login.php` in Wordpress. There should be a single location for virtually any website where you login. This is where retaining `Set-Cookie` (and passing it to your client) is important. Elsewhere you can strip/ignore it. As for Varnish note, just noting it's more flexible/pretty to configure, but in no way it's better if you can do things in NGINX only. Unless you use ESI (cache blocks), which is a different story.

Comment: I know what login location is not what i asked if not in location i need to put as same php block and only not setup fastcgi_ignore_headers.

Anyways, i tried everything in configuration location and still not work, visitor in random pages is "logged" into in users, i mean visitor see "welcome to username" when tried to navigete in user account of course can't modify anything but still seems logged as.

I tried to remove fastcgi_ignore_headers in php block  but cache always says "miss" so is not storing cache.

Really i not sure what i can do login not store in cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can Just Add a Cookie for the login users, and just add this cookie value to the cache key like this

```
fastcgi_cache_key  "$cookie_user_id$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
```

also, you should find a good way to encrypt and decrypt this value for more security